# Woocommerce href's for Cart, Checkout, My Account are all empty.

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have gone through every conceivable update to try and get this to work.

I have a clients blog where we're trying to implement Woocommerce, but despite working when we first lauched, something has gone wrong recently and I cannot track it down.

I have gone through both options listed here:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

I have updated Wordpress in the dashboard, this caused issues so I then updated it manually and ftp'd all the content to the site, after reading this.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-after-41-upgrade#post-6349382

Then I had a notification that Woocommerce could be updated, so I took advantage of that.

I have also tried disabling and re-enabling woocommerce, and deleting and reinstalling it. The only weird discrepancy is that in the previous version if I checked the woocommerce pages in the dashboard, I could see these hooks:

```
[woocommerce_checkout]
[woocommerce_cart]
```

But now those are not present and the page is not editable, but I assume this is part of the latest woocommerce version.

I also tried to enable stable wordpress themes (twentytwelve and twentyfifteen) to see if there was a conflict with my child theme, but that didn't solve anything. This is as per the advice here:
https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203112147-How-to-Get-Help

Here is a screenshot from one of my empty href's.

[image: Empty href]

I realise this is a vague question with no code referenced, but I just don't know what is going on.

I can send a link to the site if that helps I am just hoping someone else has also come up against this issue.

Comment: In your dashboard go to WooCommerce > Settings and check in every tab that the right page is linked...

Comment: Wow @Rich so simple. I haven't seen that mentioned anywhere. Thank you. If you want to put it in an answer I will vote on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dashboard go to WooCommerce > Settings and check in every tab that the right page is linked. This will allow the Woo links to work correctly.